# Using Bank Statement from Online Banking for Canada Visa application

Tags: visas, canada, online-resources, proof-provenance-of-funds

I want to ask a question, (background) i am from Nigeria and i will be submitting TRV application for Canada (Visit Visa), Now i have a question i want to ask as per bank statements. I bank with a Bank and when i want to demand my bank statements i just use my Mobile Banking application, and it sends the statement to my Email, thereafter i can download and use for whatever purpose..

Now here comes the question i want to ask, Can i use the account statement generated from my internet banking for submission for the visa application alongside other documentations as well, or do I have to get it stamped by the bank as well?

Answer (score 2):

The [special instructions](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5873E.pdf) for filing the visa application from Lagos state only that you need to submit "copies of bank statements for the last three months". No special stamping is required. If the bank sent you PDF documents then you can simply upload those PDF documents directly with your online visa application.

The instructions also say you also need to submit: "Any additional relevant documentation (employment letter, pay slips, proof of pension, business registration, investments, etc.)" This documentation should show the sources of the money deposited into your bank account over the three month time period covered by the bank statements, and any other money you may have access to, which Canada will use to evaluate your application.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your statements shows the correct bank and account information, and it is not forged nor fudged, you will be fine. Most banks today use paperless statements so it is not uncommon to provide printouts of pdf files as bank statements when applying for visas. However, make sure that your statements work in your favour and not against: avoid funds parking and erratic banking behaviours. See [our extremely detailed question on the topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) for more information.